# setting parameter in firebase functions

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Hi i am using below code in index.js. Here i want to set one value in "Default welcome intent"  and i want to take in "Test Intent". How to do this. I want to pass this value in background and i want to use it

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var functions = require("firebase-functions");
var gApp = require("actions-on-google");
var WebhookClient = require('dialogflow-fulfillment').WebhookClient;
var _a = require('dialogflow-fulfillment'), Card = _a.Card, Suggestion = _a.Suggestion;
var app = gApp.dialogflow({ debug: true });
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug';
//exports.dialogflowSample = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => 
//{
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', function (conv, input) {
    conv.ask("Welcome to my dialogFlow agent!");
});
app.intent('Test Intent', function (conv, input) {
    conv.ask('<speak>Testing the application' + ("<say-as >" + input + "</say-as></speak>"));
    conv.ask('<speak>Testing the application' + "<say-as >" + qNo + "</say-as></speak>");
});
exports.dialogflowSample = functions.https.onRequest(app);
//});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to pass this value in background"?

Comment: i got answer.  my question is, i want to re-use few values and those values should not shown to user and i will use the values in other intents call. For i am using conv.data.****** .